# Is there a command to add new line in a text file if the value of that row is different to the next?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which is sorted using sort -n. However, in order to make a surface plot in gnuplot, I need there to be a blank line between lines with differing values of the first column. for example

```
1.0
1.0
1.1
1.1
```

to:

```
1.0
1.0

1.1
1.1
```

is there any way to do this easily with Ubuntu Linux?

Answer (score 5):

I'd write it:

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $0 != last {print ""}
     {print; last = $0}' < your-file
```

Note that as long as the lines consist of numbers, that `$0 != last` will be a *numeric* comparison, for which `1.0` is the same as `1` or `1e0` or `1.00` (though not necessarily 0x1, and also beware of the potential effect of the locale with regards to the treatment of the decimal separator (1.0 vs 1,0)). If you want to ensure a lexical comparison, change that to  `$0 "" != last`.

Depending on the `awk` implementation, that will enforce either a `memcmp()` (byte-to-byte comparison), `strcmp()` (same, but can't handle NUL bytes), `strcoll()` (whether the two strings sort the same) or `wcsncmp()` (character-to-character as opposed to byte to byte) comparison (all of which should be equivalent if your input consists only of decimal digits and period characters).

If you want to force byte-to-byte comparison, fix the locale to C:

```
LC_ALL=C awk 'NR > 1 && $0 "" != last {print ""}
              {print; last = $0}' < your-file
```

(again, some `awk` implementations will choke on the NUL character).

Answer (score 3):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {A=""} {if ($0!=A) { printf "\n%s\n", $0; A=$0} else print $0}'
```

Be careful when you choose initialization value for A to not be in the existing values

Comment: You may skip the initialization of `A` completely. It will be interpreted as an empty string.

Comment: This will add an empty line at the top of the output.